# Google Apps Script: OAuth2 Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:toType

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to access some google apis via oauth2. I have set everything up and it gives me a token with refresh token, token id and expiration time etc, but while trying to use it i get "Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:toType" as an error.

I have tried changing headers to Header but that just leads to a "Login Required" error instead.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
var access_token = "XXXXXXX";
var config={"method":"GET",
            "muteHttpExceptions":true,
            "contentType":"application/json",
            "headers":{
            "Authorization":"Bearer "+access_token
            },
            "responseType":"json"};
var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config).getContentText();
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the official [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2)

> **Modifying the access token payload**
>
> Some OAuth providers, such as the Smartsheet API, require you to add a hash to the access token
> request payloads. The setTokenPayloadHandler method allows you to pass
> in a function to modify the payload of an access token request before
> the request is sent to the token endpoint:

```
 // Set the handler for modifying the access token request payload:
 .setTokenPayloadHandler(myTokenHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out urlfetchapp was pulling the prototype functuons along with the object. In my case toType was an Object.prototype function and uppon checking with getRequest() the ebtire function was pullled along with the object header.